# Are “lb” or “lbs” ever pronounced differently from “pound(s)”?

Tags: pronunciation, slang, abbreviations

The “standard” pronunciation of *lb* or *lbs* is the same as for *pound(s).*

However, given the nature of humans, I find it likely that in some slang a pronunciation based on the written word is used, e.g., /lɒb/. I am curious whether my guess is correct, i.e., whether such a pronunciation exists.

Unfortunately, searching the Internet for this did not give any satisfying (positive or negative) results, as it primarily yields non-slang dictionary entries, which only give the standard pronunciation.

Comment: The unit is descended from the Roman *libra* (hence the abbreviation "lb"); The name pound is a Germanic adaptation of the Latin phrase libra pondo, "a pound by weight" See[Roman measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(mass)). In my experience it is always pronounced *pound* in English. Though in other languages, such as French -*livre* -, it is closer to its Latin original.

Comment: Nope. Always 'pounds'

Comment: Well, I always pronounce them "lub" and "lubs".  (But then, I do get a lot of strange looks.)

Comment: In fully modern (metric) Australia, kilograms have replaced pounds, and use the standard abbreviation "kg" (singular and plural), It is called "kilograms" in most formal / normal speech, but also "kilos" ("He's lost ten kilos in a month or two."), "kay-gees", and also "kegs", with this last usage mostly associated with the weight that racehorses carry.

Comment: We also use "clicks" as common slang for kilometres (distance - 0.62 miles), or more usually kilometres per hour (speed - 80 k/h = 50 mph).

Comment: @Cargill, in the UK we seem to be stuck halfway between 'imperial' and metric: our pints seem to be sacred, and I suspect we haven't moved over from miles because of the cost of changing signage.  But mostly, we're OK with kilograms and kilos.

Comment: @HotLicks In my region, we sometimes say "libs" for pounds.

Comment: In many hotels (pubs) "pints" and "half-pints" are still the names of beers, however the actual glasses are labelled in millilitres.  In fact, even though Australia is remarkable homogeneous across its English dialect, the names of beers in the various states is one area of great variation. We noticed the very mixed world in the UK indeed.

Comment: I'm suprised, though I guess I shouldn't have been, by @Kit's response.  I have never heard of anyone referring to points as anything resembling lbs.   I was just about to say so in an answer when I read the comment.  I wonder who the "we" is that says "libs" and in what context they could hope to be understood?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox: You may want to turn that into an answer.

Comment: I have on occasion heard an arch "el bees", but I don't recall hearing "libs"

Answer (score 10):

This is the only instance I have ever heard of, of someone pronouncing "lbs." as something other than "pounds."  Since it's intended as a joke on Lucy's naive understanding, I'd say it's clear enough:  few do this even as slang, except as a joke or a mistake.  (And if it weren't for Kit's comment above, I'd say "nobody.")

[image: Peanuts cartoon about "ozzes" and "libs"]